# How do I stop Google Docs from opening documents in new tabs?

Tags: google-docs

Is there any way to stop Google Docs from opening documents in new tabs?

For example, when I use Google Docs, and when I click on a document, the UI always opens a new tab. It's really frustrating (I would like it to open the new page on the same tab).

Is there anyway we can tell the browser that I would like documents not opened in new tabs?

Comment: Links in docs or docs themselves?

Comment: @Eight I'm not understanding you.. I mean Links to the docs, that I click when I want to edit a document

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*As [noted by Felipe Alvarez](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19782/how-do-i-stop-google-docs-from-opening-documents-in-new-tabs/19783?noredirect=1#comment40506_19783), this is no longer available as an option. Therefore, while this answer was correct two years ago when the product was Google Docs, it no longer applies to the current Google Drive app.*

---

Assuming you mean opening documents from your list, that's in the Google Docs settings on the "General" tab.

> Where items open:

Your choices are:

- In a new window
- In the current window

Screen shot:

[image: Google Docs settings screen shot]

Select the latter for what you want.

Comment: Damn cool, this should've  been the default

Comment: I believe it was only recently added.

Comment: no longer an option to open in same window. Docs always open in new tab.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know if the links from within a Google doc are always opening in a new tab on a global basis (all browsers) has been solved, but if not, I found that when a Google doc is called from **outside**, it is opened in the same tab as the host document.

But, I had put a menu in a Google doc in which each link within the menu to another Google Doc opened in a new tab.

To solve this, I took the menu and put it into a page/post on my host site (WordPress site/blog).

All links within the Google Docs continued to be opened in a new tab, but at least the main menu problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this issue myself by deleting the google docs/google drive editor extension. On the help site for google it said to delete all my extensions, but just deleting that one did the trick. :)