# How do I stop Google Docs from opening document-relative links in new tabs?

Tags: google-docs, links

Similar to [How do I stop Google Docs from opening documents in new tabs?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19782/how-do-i-stop-google-docs-from-opening-documents-in-new-tabs), how do I open internal links *within* a Google Doc in the same tab?

Specific scenario -- I've [manually created a link to a header](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/30321/23626), I click on that link, it gives me the pop-up where I can either click, remove, or edit the url.  I click that url, which is a link to an anchor in the same document, but it opens a new tab.